# Ag grid: Array object values is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ag-grid

How to load the following array object mark "name" values in cell.

Here the object looks like

```
 {
      id: "1"
      mark: [
        0: {name: "AUS", id: 1000}
        1: {name: "BRA", id: 1050}
        2: {name: "CHN", id: 1100}
        3: {name: "ECE", id: 1200}
        4: {name: "EG", id: 1250}
        5: {name: "JAP", id: 1450}
        6: {name: "RUS", id: 1500}
      ]
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-balham cis-ag-grid"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [rowData]="rowData"
      [context]="context" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
      (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)' (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS**
Inside constructor (),

```
this.defaultColDef = {
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      headerComponentParams: { menuIcon: 'fa fa-filter' }
    };

this.columnDefs = [  
{
  headerName: "ID",            
  minWidth: 144,
  field: "id", 
  valueGetter: "data.id"
},
{
  headerName: "Mark",            
  minWidth: 144,
  field: "mark", 
  valueGetter: "data.mark.name"
}];
```

currently, It is displaying in grid column cell like,

```
ID        Mark
--------------
1         [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], 
          [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
```

**Expected is,**

```
ID        Mark
  --------------
   1       AUS, BRA, CHN, ECE, EG,JAP,RUS
```

Comment: Show the HTML file and component code

Comment: Updated the post  with expected result

Comment: Hi, I am asking about `.html` and `.ts` file.

Comment: Updated the post HTML and ts

Answer (score 2):

Try to this for Ag-grid.

**Set Column:-**

```
constructor() {
 this.columnDefs = [                    
  {
    headerName: 'Id', sortable: true, resizable: true, valueGetter: 'data.mark.id'
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Mark', sortable: true, resizable: true, valueGetter: 'data.mark.name'
  }
 ]
}
```

**In typescript file :-**

```
public dataMarkList:any;

constructor() {

}

yourGetFunction() {
   this.dataMarkList = data.mark
}
```

And set `rowData` properties in ag-grid like

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 200px);" rowSelection="single"
   animateRows="true" [rowHeight]="43" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" rowModelType="infinite"
   paginationPageSize="50" [rowData]="dataMarkList">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Can you please provide right code for this [rowData]="dataMarkList". This is not working. Also column filter data is not updating based on the grid data.

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't any HTML code provided, you can try:

```
<span *ngFor="let obj of data.mark">
 {{ obj.name }},
</span>
```

inside that HTML `column`.

It's coming as `[object Object]` because it an object (`{name: "AUS", id: 1000}`). You can visualize it by putting pipe as `| json` in `{{ obj | json }}`

Comment: I'm using ag grid directive. Not the html

Answer (score 0):

there is no html provided so a reproducible plunker or stackblitz will help. 
Try like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataList">
     <span *ngFor="let item of data.mark">
        {{ item .name }},
      </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Update the post. I'm using ag-grid directive.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer) to accomplish this.  I use Vue not Angular.  This is how I did it in Vue.

I created a `Cell Renderer` component file called `CellRenderList.vue` and imported it into the parent. For defining the field in the parent file I did.

```
headerName: 'SomeName',
field: 'mark',
cellRendererFramework: 'CellRendererList',
```

Importing the component and adding that cell renderer line should be the only thing you need to do on your original file.

My `CellRenderList.vue` component file looks like this.

```
<template>
 <div class="">
  <span v-for="(value, index) in mark">
    <span v-if="index != 0">, </span><span>{{ value.name }}</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CellRendererList',
    computed: {
      mark() {
        return this.params.data.mark
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The Ag Grid documentation on `Cell Renderer` has some good examples how to do it in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.columnDefs = [  
{
  headerName: "ID",            
  minWidth: 144,
  field: "id",
},
{
  headerName: "Mark",            
  minWidth: 144,
  field: "mark", 
  valueGetter: (row: any) => {
        return row.data.mark.name;
      },
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
{
  headerName: 'SomeName',
  field: 'mark',
  valueGetter: (row: any) => {
    return row.data.mark.map((mark: any) => profile.name);
  },
},
```